# SVN Branching and "IIS Url Already Mapped to Different Location"

Tags: svn, iis

I maintain several subversion development branches on my development pc and build box.

How do you guys deal with opening a solution on one branch and having IIS get configured to that location.  Then opening the same solution / project in a different branch / location and get "IIS Url Already Mapped to Different Location" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I added localhost.branch to my host file
2. In IIS I created a new website mapped to host header localhost.branch.
3. I searched and replaced `<IISUrl>http://localhost/myapp</IISUrl>` with `<IISUrl>http://localhost.branch/myapp</IISUrl>` in all my csproj files in the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, delete the file from the connections in the iis.  Go back to visual studio and reload the file.  Again, it will ask to create a virtual directory, press ok.